# $i=0 while loop edit

Tags: php, while-loop

I think this is fairly simple, just not a php coder. Researching and reading posts I narrowed down my issue to this piece of code, but not sure how to edit. Things found and tried throw error.

The following code works fine and gives me the results for the current date (today) and previous 6 days.  I want to try and change so rather than obtaining the past I want to show the future events. So today and next 6 days.

```
$i=0;
while ($i<=6){
    $labeldate=date('m/d',mktime(0,0,0,$sm,$sd-$i,$sy));
    $_SESSION['statistic_week'] = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$sm,$sd-$i,$sy));

    $statistic = querySQL('statistic_week_def');
    foreach ($statistic as $row) {
        $statistic_week_def[$i] = ($row->paxsum) ? $row->paxsum : 0; 
    }
    $labels[] = $labeldate;

$i++;
}
```

Comment: try `$sd+i`  instead of  `$sd-i` like this `$labeldate=date('m/d',mktime(0,0,0,$sm,$sd+$i,$sy));`

Comment: update only this statement $_SESSION['statistic_week'] = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$sm,$sd+$i, $sy));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use +$i in the date functions instead of -$i, this will add days rather then subtract them.

```
$i=0;
while ($i<=6){
    $labeldate=date('m/d',mktime(0,0,0,$sm,$sd+$i,$sy));
    $_SESSION['statistic_week'] = date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$sm,$sd+$i,$sy));

    $statistic = querySQL('statistic_week_def');
    foreach ($statistic as $row) {
        $statistic_week_def[$i] = ($row->paxsum) ? $row->paxsum : 0; 
    }
    $labels[] = $labeldate;

$i++;
}
```

Comment: That worked... thanks everyone. I knew it was something simple, but beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($i <= 6) {
        $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $sm, $sd + $i, $sy)
        $labeldate = date('m/d', $time);
        $_SESSION['statistic_week'] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        $statistic = querySQL('statistic_week_def');
        foreach ($statistic as $row) {
            $statistic_week_def[$i] = ($row->paxsum) ? $row->paxsum : 0; 
        }
        $labels[] = $labeldate;
        $i++;
    }
?>
```